# Running test with propery file filtered by maven

Tags: java, maven, testng

I want to be able to config values in some property file that lately is being used by Java tests.
Here is my pom.xml

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>env-dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <target.env>http://myurl.com</target.env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Properties file

```
targetEnv=${target.env}
```

When I run `mvn install -Denv=dev` I can see that in target folder, the properties file is getting the right value but during the tests the placeholder is being used where I want to use the real value when tests are running.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

First of all, don't use profiles to switch between environments. Especially a unit-test should never be aware of any environment settings. Please remove it in this case.
For filtering test resources you should use the `<testResources/>`-tag instead.